# Next Image component throws 404 error in production, works fine in development

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have a bunch of images in a hidden gallery, only shown when a user clicks on a certain button.

On the development server, everything is fine, no errors or issues, but when I deploy my website and open the gallery the images don't show and throw a 404 error in the console (I included the required props).

When I replace the `<Image/>` component with `<img>`, everything is fine on the development server and live. Can anyone please help? I searched a lot and I didn't find anything like this issue.

Answer (score 4):

### My solution:

I had the same issue and solved it by renaming the image file names.

### How the issue arose:

I had renamed the images, only changing uppercase to lowercase letters. This resulted in the files being wrongly named in my github repository. After a rename with new characters, the files were correctly updated on github.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder on root call it 'static' which is bassically /static/imagename.png

Set the source to the image like so;

```
<img src="/static/imagename.png" />
```

This should load the static image in file both in dev environment and build file.

Answer (score 0):

Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.

#### Possible solutions:

- Use `next start`, which starts the Image Optimization API.
- Use Vercel to deploy, which supports Image Optimization.
- Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.

That means: `Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available`

To solve this problem. I just used [next-optimized-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-optimized-images) for static image and `next/image` for images from the cloud.

Kindly read this article for more understanding: https://dev.to/jameswallis/next-image-and-next-optimized-images-a-brief-comparison-4c4i